# SQL Server : UPPER last five chars

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following working query :

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(
        AddressLine1, RIGHT( AddressLine1, 5 ),
        UPPER( RIGHT( AddressLine1, 5 ) )
    )
FROM Person.Address
```

There is other way to do that ?

Comment: you're doing it right..

Comment: You are not right.  If the last five characters appear multiple times in the address, then your method will upper case all occurrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use concatenation:

```
select left(addressline1, len(addressline1) - 5) + upper(right(addressline1, 5))
from person.address;
```

Your method is dangerous, because there is no guarantee that the last five characters only appear once in the address.

Hmmm, you can also do:

```
select stuff(addressline1, len(addressline1) - 4, 5, upper(right(addressline1, 5)))
from person.address;
```

Both these formulations assume that `addressline1` has at least 5 characters.  If shorter addresses are possible, then a `case` is probably the easiest solution.

Comment: your stuff start parameter is off.. should be `len(addressline1) - 4`..   neither option handles < 5 characters (which you mention).. i think he has it right

Comment: @JamieD77 . . . HIs method is not correct, for the reason that I point out in the comment and in this answer.  Fixing these for < 5 characters is trivial.

Comment: You're right it "could" happen with some strange address